# How to come to $ \sum_{i=0}^n k = {(n+1)\cdot (n+2)\over 2} $ this equation?

Tags: calculus, functions

How to come from this equation to

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n k = {n(n+1)\over 2} + (n+1)
$$

this equation:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n k = {(n+1)(n+2)\over 2}
$$

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: Have you tried getting a common denominator in the first equation and seeing if you can get it to factor into the second equation?

Comment: That is, the $(n+1)$ in the second summand of the first displayed equation is equal to $\frac{2(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: The sum of the first n odd numbers is n squared, use some algebraic manipulation to get your sum, and its n(n+1)/2

Comment: You can't, as the problem is stated. The second equality should be $\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\;k$.

Comment: As stated this is not correct. $\sum_{i=0}^nk$ should be replaced by $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}k$ everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{2(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)+2(n+1)}{2}=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}$$